# Is SharePoint knowledge still a main stream skill?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp

I myself is a SharePoint consultant for more than 10 years and has helped lots of clients to solve their business needs by using SharePoint components like Workflow, InfoPath, WebParts, Document Management solutions etc.
But as Microsoft moved to cloud, it has taken out SharePoint components and started offering them as a separate services (which is good, in my opinion). For example, InfoPath is replaced with PowerApps, Workflow is replaced by PowerAutomate, Document Management is better via MS Teams Channels (which are behind the scenes SharePoint Folders for document storage), Team Sites are mostly exposed as Teams in MS Teams etc.

So what I feel is that SharePoint is now more of a behind the scene system rather than a centre stage server offering. Due to this, I think there will not be much demand for **SharePoint Consultants** but SharePoint knowledge will become an additional skill for **Power Platform Consultants**

What do you think is my observation correct or am I missing something?